# Cannot call Keras from Slurm

Tags: keras, slurm

I want to use Keras on a cluster using Slurm as the job engine.

If I open a terminal and run the following commands, everything works fine:

```
$python
>>> import tensorflow
>>> import keras
```

However, if I place `import tensorflow` and `import keras` in a Python file that I then call from slurm :

```
srun [bunch of parameters for my cluster] python mypythonfile.py
```

Then I get the following error: `ImportError: No module named keras`.

Is there something specific to do when using Keras in a cluster with Slurm?

Comment: Are you certain that they’re using the same Python installation? You may have to start your script with a `module load foo`

Comment: Thanks a lot, you are right! Slurm use python 2.7 when I automatically load/use python 3.4

Comment: In case there are several build versions, run `module spider keras` This will result in a list with available build versions. You can choose an appropriate one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm reiterating my comment just to show that this question has been answered:

---

It's common to `module load xxxx` where `xxxx` is a different Python installation than the default. You usually stick this in your `.bash_profile` or a similar file to make sure that you have the Python version you want, always available.

When you submit a job with Slurm, it doesn't call your `.bash_profile`. It just executes the script. You need to make sure that loading your Python distribution is part of that script.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Any idea how I ask Slurm to load the good python environment first?

Comment: Add the `module load anaconda` or whatever to the start of the script you submit.

Answer (score 2):

I also met this problem and solved it recently. As the above answer mentioned, slurm command won't excute .bash_profile and the reason that you can import kears directly in python is the environment setting sentence in the .bash_profile. As a result, I added export PATH="/n/home01/username/miniconda3/bin:$PATH" into my sbatch file and then everything worked.